# Parsing and appending a link

Tags: python

I have a link as input below,i need to parse this link and append "/#c/" as shown below,any inputs on how
this can be done?

```
INPUT:-https://link.com/617394/

OUTPUT:-https://link.com/#/c/617394/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"https://link.com/617394/".replace("m/6","m/#/c/6")
```

although I suspect your real problem is something else

```
"com/#/c/".join("https://link.com/617394/".split("com/"))
```

may be slightly more applicable to your actual problem statement (which I still dont know what that is)

```
my_link =  "https://link.com/617394/"
print re.sub("\.(com|org|net)/",".\\1/#/c/",my_link)
```

maybe more of what your actually looking for ...

that urlsplit solution of @JonClements is pretty dang sweet too

Comment: above link is just one example...the solution has to be generic..any given link I should be able to append /#/c

Comment: @JonClements - "/#/c" should be appended right before the number...any link will have a number and the number will be the one after last "/"

Answer (score 4):

Try something such as:

```
from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

s = 'https://link.com/617394/'
split = urlsplit(s)
new_url = urlunsplit(split._replace(path='/#/c' + split.path))
# https://link.com/#/c/617394/
```

Comment: I was trying to make this answer and couldn't for the life of me figure out how to actually change the dang path! What an unusual syntax for it

Comment: @mhlester it's only because it's a `namedtuple` - otherwise, it's more painful :)